# Custom list definition solution migrated and not rendering the Sharepoint:Formfield controls

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, upgrade, solution-package, 2019

I have a NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx from a custom list defined by a WSP where the `SharePoint:FormField` controls stop to render after the page is loaded for the first time after deployed (not upgraded).

**The full history is:** I converted a content database from 2010 to 2019 and now I’m converting the solution responsible for this list. However, when I deploy the solution for the first time after I migrate it to 2019, the NewForm and EditForm render the `SharePoint:FormField` controls only in the first and then not anymore.

I already tried to change the assembly version of the Registers and even the SharePoint Product Version of the package file from 14 to 19. But when I do that, SharePoint is not finding anymore the custom forms. It only finds if I keep the SharePoint Product Version to 14.

Does someone went through a situation similar to this too?

Comment: I've got this exact issue with hundreds of forms. Did you ever find a solution?